# Intuition behind understanding eigenvectors and Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning-model, linear-algebra

I am struggling to understand linear algebra application in machine learning, and I am not able to answer the following question.
Is the model learned in Machine Learning  the eigenvector of the features matrix?

Comment: The term 'eigenvector of the features matrix' is generally not defined; the features matrix can be expected to be non-square (you want more samples than features; hopefully, many more so!), so they don't have eigenvectors.

Comment: This is actually vague question, there are many approaches in machine learning and certainly many of them do not involve linear algebra nor eigen-vectors. On the other hand, [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) for example, which can form part of machine learning pipeline to define features certainly involves eigen-vectors.